# Proving vector calculus identity $\nabla \times (\mathbf a\times \mathbf b) =\cdots$ using Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, index-notation

I want to prove the following relation

$$\nabla \times (\mathbf a\times \mathbf b) = \mathbf a\nabla \cdot \mathbf  b + \mathbf  b \cdot \nabla \mathbf  a - \mathbf  b \nabla \cdot \mathbf  a - \mathbf a \cdot \nabla \mathbf  b$$

using the following Levi-Civita definition of cross product
$$\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b} =\mathbf{e}_i \epsilon_{ijk}a_ib_j$$
where $\epsilon_{ijk} =\begin{cases}
+1 & \text{if } i,j,k \text{ are in clockwise permutation}, \\
-1 & \text{if } i,j,k \text{ are in counterclockwise permutation, and} \\
\;\;\,0 & \text{if }i=j \text{ or } j=k \text{ or } k=i.
\end{cases}$

Comment: Are those dots on my screen? :p

Comment: @FrenzYDT. : try cleaning it ;)

Comment: Try writing out the right hand side using the corresponding expressions, e.g., $\nabla\cdot b = \partial_i b_i$.

Comment: Did you check in textbooks? Why not ask references?

Comment: @vesszabo : sadly i don't have any reference . I am just trying myself to solve it . trying to generalize cross product

Comment: Just found [this page](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=257144). question b). Is this of help? Second floor.

Comment: @FrenzYDT. : looks very useful . I'll go through it . :)

Comment: @Theorem I've edited your post - to write in LaTeX what you had in your picture. If you are satisfied with the result, you can remove the picture. (Or you can further edit the post. But anyway, I think that in general it's better to use LaTeX/Mathjax than to include a picture.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak : Thank you .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Proof

Courtesy of [this thread from PhysicsForums](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=257144).

\begin{align}
\nabla \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{B})
&=\partial_l \hat{e}_l \times (a_i b_j \hat{e}_k \epsilon_{ijk}) \\
&=\partial_l a_i b_j \epsilon_{ijk} \underbrace{ (\hat{e}_l \times \hat{e}_k)}_{(\hat{e}_l \times \hat{e}_k) = \hat{e}_m \epsilon_{lkm} } \\
&=\partial_l a_i b_j \hat{e}_m \underbrace{\epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{mlk}}_{\text{contracted epsilon identity}} \\
&=\partial_l a_i b_j \hat{e}_m \underbrace{(\delta_{im} \delta_{jl} - \delta_{il} \delta_{jm})}_{\text{They sift other subscripts}} \\
&=\partial_j (a_i b_j \hat{e}_i)- \partial_i (a_i b_j \hat{e}_j) \\
&=\color{blue}{a_i \partial_j b_j \hat{e}_i + b_j \partial_j a_i \hat{e}_i} - (\color{green}{a_i \partial_i b_j \hat{e}_j + b_j \partial_i a_i \hat{e}_j}) \\
&= \vec{A}(\nabla \cdot \vec{B}) + (\vec{B} \cdot \nabla)\vec{A} - (\vec{A} \cdot \nabla)\vec{B} - \vec{B}(\nabla \cdot \vec{A}) \\
\end{align}

> Edit: As is pointed out by @enzotib, the blue and green sums are derivatives of products.

#### Why did the deltas vanish?

Due to [Kronecker $\delta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Properties_of_the_delta_function)'s sifting property. Recall the definition of Kronecker delta:

$$\delta_{ij}=\begin{cases}
0,\quad \text{if } i\ne j, \\
1,\quad \text{if } i=j.
\end{cases}$$

Thus, for $j\in\mathrm Z$:

$$\sum\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}a_i\delta_{ij} = a_j$$

This is just like *filtering* (or *sifting*), because only when $i=j$ does $\delta_{ij} = 1$. Other terms are zeroes. This also works for partial derivatives.

For example,

$$\partial_l a_i b_j \hat{e}_m \delta_{im} \delta_{jl} = \partial_l a_i b_j \hat{e}_i \delta_{jl}$$

- If $l\ne j$ then $\partial_l a_i b_j \hat{e}_i \delta_{jl} = \partial_l a_i b_j \hat{e}_i(0) = 0$;
- If $l=j$ then $\partial_l a_i b_j \hat{e}_i \delta_{jl} = \partial_j a_i b_j \hat{e}_i (1) = \partial_j a_i b_j \hat{e}_i$.

Thus,
$$\partial_l a_i b_j \hat{e}_m \delta_{im} \delta_{jl} =\partial_j (a_i b_j \hat{e}_i).$$

Note that $\hat{e}_i$ is a `const std::vector<int>`.

#### Some thoughts

1. There are two cross products (one of them is Curl) and we use different subscripts (of partials and [Levi-Civita symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) to distinguish them, e.g., $l$ for the curl and $k$ for $\vec{A} \times \vec{B}$.
2. We move the variables around quite often.
3. The cross product of two basis is explained in the underbrace.
4. The contracted epsilon identity is very useful. We replaced them by [Kronecker $\delta$-s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).
5. [Kronecker $\delta$-s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Properties_of_the_delta_function) are known to select things efficiently.
6. In many proofs of vector calculus identities (this one included), we add and substract extra terms.
7. Do I love Levi-Civita symbols and Einstein Notation? I'm ambivalent.

Comment: The last step is simply the derivative of a product, first $\partial_j a_i b_j$ and then $\partial_i a_i b_j$. There are errors, though.

Comment: @FrenzYDT. : Can you explain me how u changed $\partial_l$ to $\partial_j$. didn't get how you got rid of  $\delta$.

Comment: @Theorem We have to apply the sifting property twice. If delta is zero then the partial derivative with respect to that variable is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out one quick but tentative proof using skew-symmetric matrices and expecting to be verified.
The product of two skew-symmetric matrices is
$\mathbf{S}_\vec{A}\mathbf{S}_\vec{B}\vec{x}=\left[\vec{B}\vec{A}^T-(\vec{A}\vec{B}^T)\mathbb{I}\right]\vec{x}$
or in dyadic direct multiplication:
$$\begin{align}
(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\times \mathbb{I}&=\mathbb{I}\times (\vec{a}\times\vec{b})=\vec{b}\vec{a}-\vec{a}\vec{b}.\\
{(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\times \mathbb{I}}\cdot\vec{x}&=(\vec{a}\times \vec{b})\times \vec{x}=(\vec{b}\vec{a}-\vec{a}\vec{b})\cdot\vec{x}\\
\vec{x}\times (\vec{a}\times \vec{b})&=\vec{x}\cdot(\vec{b}\vec{a}-\vec{a}\vec{b}).
\end{align}$$
where $\mathbf{S}_\vec{A}=\vec{A}\times$ is the skew-symmetric matrix about vector $\vec{A}$, likely for $\mathbf{S}_\vec{B}$, and $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity matrix which can also be omitted.
Let $\vec{e}$ be unit vector, so
$$\begin{align}
[\nabla \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{B})]\cdot\vec{e}&=\nabla\cdot\left[ (\vec{A} \times \vec{B})]\times\vec{e}\right]=\nabla\cdot\left[\vec{B}\vec{A}^T-(\vec{A}\vec{B}^T)\mathbb{I}\right]\vec{e}\\
&=\left[\nabla {\cdot }\left(\vec{B}\vec{A}^T\right)-\nabla {\cdot }\left(\vec{A}\vec{B}^T\right)\right]\vec{e}
\end{align}$$